# PDFcrowd PHP PDF Generator API create href trigger

Tags: php

I'm using the following sample code to generate a PDF from a URL, you'll notice the PDF is generated automatically.  I need to be able to change this functionality to use a button or href to trigger the $pdf variable.  You'll notice two versions of the code, one with my href attempt that does not appear to work but shows a white screen.

Works fine but runs automatically:

```
<?php
require 'pdfcrowd.php';

try
{   
    // create an API client instance
    $client = new Pdfcrowd("user", "apikey");

    // convert a web page and store the generated PDF into a $pdf variable
    $pdf = $client->convertURI('http://www.home-tech.com/'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    // set HTTP response headers
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
    header("Accept-Ranges: none");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"google_com.pdf\"");

    // send the generated PDF 
    echo $pdf;
}
?>
<html>
<body>
hello world
<input name="" type="text" value="8989">
</body>
</html>
```

My attempt to initiate the PDF generation with a href:

```
<?php
require 'pdfcrowd.php';

//try
//{   
    // create an API client instance
    $client = new Pdfcrowd("user", "apikey");

    // convert a web page and store the generated PDF into a $pdf variable
    $pdf = $client->convertURI('http://www.home-tech.com/'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    // set HTTP response headers
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
    header("Accept-Ranges: none");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"google_com.pdf\"");

    // send the generated PDF 
    // echo $pdf;
//}
?>
<html>
<body>
hello world
<input name="" type="text" value="8989">
<a href="<?php echo $pdf; ?>">PDF Create</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume this is named file.pdf

```
<?php

if($_GET['pdf']=='YES'){

require 'pdfcrowd.php';

    // create an API client instance
    $client = new Pdfcrowd("user", "apikey");

    // convert a web page and store the generated PDF into a $pdf variable
    $pdf = $client->convertURI('http://www.home-tech.com/'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    // set HTTP response headers
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
    header("Accept-Ranges: none");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"google_com.pdf\"");

    // send the generated PDF 
     echo $pdf;
exit();
}
?>
<html>
<body>
hello world

<a href="file.pdf?pdf=YES">PDF Create</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect, okay I see what I was doing wrong.  Thanks so much Dagon!